# How to reference a form element in a razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a text box and then a grid under it in a razor view. The grid gets populated through a partial view rendered by a RenderAction method. I would like to put the grid's row count value in the text box. Because the view's elements are rendered top to bottom, I need to modify the textbox's text property after the grid is bound to the data source. I am using a third party grid extension which requires it to be placed in its own partial view file. I know I can modify the text property in the client but I want to do it on the server.

How do I reference a form element created by an html helper, from c# code located somewhere else in the same view file? (this question might actually be a simple one but I am drawing a blank now)

Comment: is your count text box in partial view? if it is, then why don't you count in server side render action method, place it in viewbag and then show in the textbox

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. The textbox gets rendered in the view, then the grid gets rendered and binds to the datasource and then I want to go back to the textbox and add a count to it. That's the order. This all happens in the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally against the goals of using MVC pattern, you are mixing logic across different views and that's why you will struggle to keep up with this kind of challenges.

my recommendation is to define all your data parts inside a single Viewmodel, then populating your data will be a matter of consuming instead of looping around views.

I know this may not sound as your answer, but one of the goals of stack-overflow community is to point us to the correct direction and warn us when we are heading wrong.

Comment: I am aware of all this. My constraint is the third party control and I can't have all the data in the model before rendering. I am either looking for a server side 'hack' or update the count in javascript after the view has rendered. I went with the JS route.